# SQL Query to Get Base Domains from Domain Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a field called domain that has data like this:

```
domain.com
sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.me
sub3.domain.co.uk
```

I would like to write a query that would just get the count of base domains in the database; which would be 3 based off:

```
domain.com
sub2.domain.me
sub3.domain.co.uk
```

Anyone have an idea on how I can get this done? I'm getting hung up on the domains that have multiple endings (.co.uk).

Comment: What if you have `subA.sub1.domain.com`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(TRAILING '*' FROM col), '.', 
    CASE WHEN TRIM(TRAILING '*' FROM col) LIKE '%.uk' THEN -3 ELSE -2 END))
FROM
  domains;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcf64/13).

**EDIT**

I read your question again, and I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT d1.col
FROM 
  domains d1 LEFT JOIN domains d2
  ON LOCATE(REVERSE(d2.col), REVERSE(d1.col))=1
     AND LENGTH(d1.col)>LENGTH(d2.col)
WHERE
  d2.col IS NULL
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d08b3/9).

Comment: thanks for this - I do have a bunch of different TLDs in my dataset (basically every one that exists), is there some way to make it so I wouldn't need to specify each one?

Comment: @Kirk i've updated my answer, I am not sure if it is this what you are looking for. For example, if there is `domain.com,sub1.domain.com,subA.sub1.domain.com` it will extract only domain.com because it is the shortest. Is it correct?